# Docker compose up, Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:22: bind: address already in use

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, macos, docker-machine

I'm trying to a `gitlab/gitlab-ce` image up and running with docker-compose on macOS (Big Sur) (`docker-compose up -d`). I'm using `docker-machine` with the virtualBox driver.

However, when starting the container I get the following error:

```
ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint gitlab-docker_web_1 (236233cf090b94f98e2e82c2fa795bc7f6f5ff38e2ea14f3649e87313a21d196): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:22: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

The issues is, I can't find anything running on port 22 on the host.

```
> sudo lsof -i :22
>
```

returns nothing. Running `netstat -l | grep 22` to look for listening ports I don't see anything either:

```
tcp4       0      0  byrons-mac-pro.l.61179 229.26.211.130.b.https ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  byrons-mac-pro.l.60764 108.177.122.108.imaps  ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  byrons-mac-pro.l.60761 108.177.122.108.imaps  ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  byrons-mac-pro.l.60760 108.177.122.108.imaps  ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  byrons-mac-pro.l.60759 108.177.122.108.imaps  ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  byrons-mac-pro.l.60758 108.177.122.108.imaps  ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  byrons-mac-pro.l.60755 108.177.122.108.imaps  ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  byrons-mac-pro.l.60754 108.177.122.108.imaps  ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  byrons-mac-pro.l.54147 yi-in-f188.1e100.5228  ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  byrons-mac-pro.l.49743 104.22.52.136.https    ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  byrons-mac-pro.l.49734 yv-in-f188.1e100.5228  ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  byrons-mac-pro.l.49556 108.177.122.95.https   ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  byrons-mac-pro.l.49173 17.57.144.150.5223     ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  byrons-mac-pro.l.61183 52.96.122.50.https     TIME_WAIT
tcp4       0      0  byrons-mac-pro.l.61182 52.96.122.50.https     TIME_WAIT
udp4       0      0  byrons-mac-pro.l.56826 108.177.122.139.https
c0fd8701c6b3232b stream      0      0                0 c0fd8701c6b32263                0                0
c0fd8701c6b32263 stream      0      0                0 c0fd8701c6b3232b                0                0
c0fd8701b7e36583 stream      0      0 c0fd8701b9bb407b                0                0                0 /var/folders/yt/c5z_l8554mq_fc3f0c5tpw600000gn/T/dotnet-diagnostic-2202-1621045110-socket
c0fd8701add5cb63 stream      0      0                0 c0fd8701add5ca9b                0                0 /var/folders/yt/c5z_l8554mq_fc3f0c5tpw600000gn/T/vscode-ipc-a70bbba5-ec65-4f40-861a-0bc122628a75.sock
c0fd8701a9b0232b dgram       0      0                0 c0fd8701a9b02263 c0fd8701a9b02263                0
c0fd8701a9b02263 dgram       0      0                0 c0fd8701a9b0232b c0fd8701a9b0232b                0
```

I'm a bit stumped. Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
web:
  image: "gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest"
  restart: always
  hostname: "byrons-mac-pro.lan"
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'http://byrons-mac-pro.lan'
      gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
      gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
      gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
      gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = 'remove@cantellyou.com'
      gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = '.........................'
      gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
      gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = 'login'
      gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
      gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false
      gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer' # Can be: 'none', 'peer', 'client_once', 'fail_if_no_peer_cert', see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html
      puma['worker_processes'] = 2
      sidekiq['max_concurrency'] = 10
      prometheus_monitoring['enable'] = false
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
    - "22:22"
  volumes:
    - "$GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab"
    - "$GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab"
    - "$GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a quirk of the fact that macOS does not have native `docker`, and thus all(?) implementations have a backing virtual machine in which the Linux kernel and dockerd are running (something that I would have thought was obvious from the `docker-machine` you are currently aware of, but ... I guess not). It is almost certainly *that* machine which is listening on 22, given that most folks actually *do* want access to that virtual machine for troubleshooting

I have better than average confidence that you can customize the virtual machine which `docker-machine` starts and ask it to bind ssh to :2222 (akin to [this](https://github.com/docker/machine/pull/2648/files)), or "cheat" and `docker-machine ssh systemctl stop sshd.service` type thing, freeing up the ssh port but from that point forward `docker-machine ssh` and maybe even `docker-machine stop` might not work as you expect